# Noise Reduction in pocketsphinx android

Tags: android, pocketsphinx, pocketsphinx-android

I am currently working on my bachelor thesis and I want to use pocketsphinx for hotword detection including noise reduction to make it work in noisy environment.

For that I downloaded the up to date pocketsphinx-android-demo, modified some things like the hotword and tested the Accuracy in a car while driving.

The Accuracy was quite low and I would like to try improve it.

In the [FAQ](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/faq/#q-how-to-do-the-noise-reduction) are some useful hints and I would like to have a look at the already implemented noise reduction algorithm (and maybe extend it)

**Questions:**

1. Is the noise reduction algorithm already implemented and used within the pocketsphinx-android-demo (***pocketsphinx-android-5prealpha-release.aar***) as default? If not, how do i activate this feature?
2. For having a look at  the noise reduction algorithm, I probably have to checkout  the source files at ***pocketsphinx* | *sphinxbase***, is that correct? If yes, which file contains the noise reduction algorithm? That would be very helpful to find out how to extend it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the noise reduction algorithm already implemented and used within the pocketsphinx-android-demo (pocketsphinx-android-5prealpha-release.aar) as default? If not, how do i activate this feature?

It is activated by default

> For having a look at the noise reduction algorithm, I probably have to checkout the source files at pocketsphinx | sphinxbase, is that correct? If yes, which file contains the noise reduction algorithm? That would be very helpful to find out how to extend it.

[sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/fe/fe_noise.c](https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinxbase/blob/master/src/libsphinxbase/fe/fe_noise.c)